# Run/Register app as Root/SecurityAgent user to make it accessible globally

Tags: macos, security, zsh, sudo, macos-big-sur

I am trying to run/register an application as _securityAgent user. However I am getting "illegal hardware instruction". In Earlier versions it used to work.Here is the terminal output.

nidhi@Nidhis-MBP ~ % sudo -u _securityAgent /Applications/Test.app/Contents/MacOS/Test
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  sudo -u _securityAgent /Applications/Test.app/Contents/MacOS/Test

Here are the attributes -

drwxrwxrwx   3 root   wheel    96 Jan 12 14:36 Test.app

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The host app must **not** have the sandbox entitlement, while the extension itself must have the sandbox entitlement.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/125508